# Function to return results of a snowflake query in the form of a json object

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have a query that I am running in **SNOWFLAKE**:

```
select years from date;
```

Which returns a data set that looks like this:

```
1984
1985
1986
....
2019
2020
2021
```

I am trying to return a JSON object that looks like this:

```
["m-1980", "m-1981"..., "m-2021"]
```

Is my function missing something?

```
import psycopg2
import json
import snowflake.connector as sf

def get_lyear():
    orig = sf.cursor()          #set the cursor object
    orig.execute('''select distinct year from schema.years''')
    row_headers=[x[0] for x in orig.description] #extract headers
    orig_json = orig.fetchall()
    converted_data=[]
    for i in orig_json:
        converted_data.append(dict(zip(rowheaders,i)))
    return json.dumps(converted_data)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html):

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT 'm-' || years::TEXT) AS res
FROM date
```

or:

```
SELECT ARRAYAGG('m-' || years::TEXT) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY years) AS res
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT years FROM dates);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Lukasz.  Any reason you want to use an array? Would you happen to know if the rest of my code looks correct? (Thanks so much by the way)

Comment: I don't understand the question in the comment "Any reason you want to use an array?". Isn't that what the original question is asking for?

Comment: sorry @FelipeHoffa - i got confused. i was wondering why he was using the array aggregate function....

Comment: @JohnWick There are two agg functions for [Semi-structured Data Aggregation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-aggregation.html#list-of-functions-by-sub-category). Here we construct an array thus I used ARRAY_AGG.

Comment: ty @LukaszSzozda

Answer (score 1):

I would rather modify the proposed solution to define the output column size after doing the cast year as string:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT 'm-' || years::TEXT**(6)**) AS res
FROM date
```

or

```
SELECT ARRAYAGG('m-' || years::TEXT**(6)**) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY years) AS res
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT years FROM dates);
```